# EF Core BulkInsert 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-bulkinsert

My EF Core BulkInsert throws error when inserting more than 80 rows, below is the example insert 80 rows data
[Insert 80 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwjfM.png)

but when i try 100rows the error as shown

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Im using JSON for the data

```
function Save() {
    var fail = {
        title: 'Data insert fail',
        message: 'refresh page to save again',
        position: 'topRight'
    };
    console.log(_oSeismics);
    if (_oSeismics.length > 0) {
        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "../PmepTempAdd/SavePmepVSP/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { data: _oSeismics },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function (data) {

            swal('Success!', 'Successfully saved.', 'success');

        });

        ajaxRequest.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) { 
            iziToast.error(
                    fail
                ); 
        });

    }

    else {

        iziToast.error(
                    fail
                );

    }

}

function NewSeismicObj() {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
    var time = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date + ' ' + time;

    console.log(dateTime)
    
    var oSeismic = {
        
        No: "",
        WellName: "",
        SurveyVspYaTdk: "",
        VspSonicCalibrationSynthetic: "",
        VspReport: "",
        VelocityWellCheckshot: "",
        WellProgramProposal: "",
        FinalWellReportEndOfWellReport: "",
        ProcessingDataSgy: "",
        RawDataSgy: "",
        Recommendation: "",
        RowCreated: dateTime
            
    };console.log(dateTime)

    return oSeismic;

}
```

Any Idea whats wrong with this code? for
80 rows runs normal, but over 80 error shown as above

Edit :

I have tried to change parameter into data but still error

PmepTempAddController.cs code

```
public JsonResult SavePmepVSP(List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp> data)
    {
        _VSPt = _db.SavePmepSeismicsVSP(data);
        TempData["success"] = "Inserted to TempPmeporary Table successfully";
        return Json(_VSP);
    }
```

Service.cs code

```
    public List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp> SavePmepSeismicsVSP(List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp> data)
    {
        _dbContext.BulkInsert(data);
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Its also depends on which parameter are you using...

```
 var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "../PmepTempAdd/SavePmepVSP/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { data: _oSeismics },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
        });
```

here you have written data: { **data**: _oSeismics },
So, in the backend, it must have something like the below...

```
public List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp> SavePmepVSP( List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp> data)
```

Note: Look at the name of parameter.

Comment: updated on the question, but still error. actually i send the json into controller first before to service file here is the code `public JsonResult SavePmepWGI(List<VerTempPmepWellGeneralInformation> data)
        {
            _WGIt = _db.SavePmepWGI(data);
            TempData["success"] = "Inserted to TempPmeporary Table successfully";
            return Json(_WGIt);
        }`

Comment: @KimKim are you getting data in controller while calling from ajax ?

Comment: yes, ajax into controller into service

Comment: then you can try something like `List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp> obj = new List<VerTempPmepSeismicVsp>(); obj = data;` and then `_dbContext.BulkInsert(obj);`